# How to add column description in cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector, cqlsh

I want to add the description of the each column in cassandra table if it is possible. While creating table or adding new column to existing table, how to add column description in cassandra table

ex: for cloumn `cyl` in table `car_data` add description "number of cylinders".

Answer (score 2):

The table has the metadata `comment` at the table level where you can set all that information, you can set it during the CREATE TABLE, or update it with ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE car_data WITH comment='cyl: number of cylinders';
```